# WooCommerce: Expand default filter with custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We sell event tickets in our woocommerce shop. the event dates are stored in custom fields. now we want to expand the woocommerce default filter with a date filter... that a user can filter „sort by date: low to high“ and „sort by date: high to low“

I mean this filter function: 
[image]

any ideas?